# folderbrowserdialog xp illegal characters

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

When calling FolderBrowserDialog from the Forms library in a WPF/C# user control, Windows XP displays invalid characters.

Code:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.Description = "Save Parts Template To:";

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MainWindow.Instance.LockUi();
    btn_MakeModule.IsEnabled = false;
    btn_SelectDefinition.IsEnabled = false;
    btn_SelectModules.IsEnabled = false;

    _mkPartsInput = tbox_SolutionName.Text.Trim() + ";" 
            + dialog.SelectedPath + ";" 
            + _ofdDefinition.FileName + ";" 
            + _fbdModules.SelectedPath + ";" 
            + _ofdDictionary.FileName;

    //Launch processing in background
    _mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_mkPartsInput);
}
```

Instead of showing "Save Parts Template To:"

I get "□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□J"

The FolderBrowserDialog works on Windows 7[x86/x64] but gives the above on WinXP[x86/x64].

I have a feeling an installed language pack may be causing this folder browser to attempt to translate the text.  Is there a way to force English for this text without any translations?

Thank you in advanced to whoever may resolve my problem.

Comment: Ive also had a lot of problems with these dialog boxes ... Once I had this problem where the app would close silently when trying to launch the dialog box. The workaround I used was to use the dialog boxes from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653556.aspx

Comment: I believe the problem may be in that the machines are Windows XP Professional 32bit with SP2. I'm going to try to upgrade them to SP3, which supports .Net 4.0.

Comment: Rectangles appear when the font doesn't have the glyph for a letter.  The machine is seriously messed up if that happens for English text.  It needs a serious whack.  Sure, SP3 is pretty whacky.

Comment: Upgrading to SP3 isnt really a solution. The app should run correctly or not run at all.

Comment: On a different machine, it was Chinese characters, but my Chinese friend said it was jibberish.